# flexslider property smoothHeight not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

i am using flexslider with its property smoothHeight set to true:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshow: true,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: "7000",
        animationSpeed: "600",
        smoothHeight: true,
    });
});
```

and then using images of different height expecting the slider to adjust to fit them. it's not doing it and i can't figure out why.

i'm using it with bootstrap and have it set to a specified max-height of 500px when above viewport width of 992px (a bootstrap breakpoint).

so at viewport 992px and below, i allow the slider to be whatever height it calculates.

check it rendered below 992px: [jsfiddle rendered result](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/qh4nZ/embedded/result/)

[editable jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/qh4nZ/)

thanks for any advice.

Comment: it looks like flexslider resizes according to variable height of all content but with the tallest image as it's baseline. the smoothHeight demo uses images of equal size: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/smooth-height

Comment: @jeanine Updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you add

```
overflow: hidden
```

to

```
.flexslider
```

or target the ID of slider it seems to solve this issue.

EDIT:
As a response to the downvote. Here's my working! example. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hy2698w/)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the last comma in the options

```
smoothHeight: true,
```

should be:

```
smoothHeight: true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While you're technically correct, the asker's problem is unlikely to be caused by this comma, because modern browsers will simply ignore it.